# Two wireless NICs on a MacBook - can I bind all VPN traffic to one, and everything else to another?

Tags: macos, vpn, wireless-networking

I frequently connect to my workplace over a VPN. I would like to continue watching videos from, say YouTube, whilst I work on the VPN, without degrading the available VPN bandwidth (say for an RDP session).

Can I configure a second NIC to deal with only the VPN traffic, with everything else going over the primary?

Specs as requested: Macbook Pro, OSX Snow Leopard, using the built in OSX VPN connectivity, the in-built airport card and a USB external wifi adapter.

Comment: My be of use http://serverfault.com/questions/100613/public-traffic-to-go-over-1-nic-and-private-traffic-to-use-another-nic

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could.  One Nic should be setup to use the settings of the vpn such as ip and then run RDC using the networks local IP.  Therefore you would be connected solely through vpn.  How?  I could not really say without knowing the particular vpn software.

For the other Nic if you are running windows.. Use an internal firewall to route.

My answer, general yes, please provide specs.. be happy to help as I can.